# How shell variables are two-tier arrays

Tags: linux, shell

```
a=(1 2)
b=(3 4 5 6)
c=(7 8 9)

z=(a b c)
for i in ${z[*]}
  do
    for j in ${${i}[*]}
      do
        echo $i
      done
  done
```

`for j in ${${i}[*]}` always output  bad substitution.What should I do

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am a novice in computer. I think pwoershell is the same as shell

Comment: PowerShell specificially refers to the Microsoft product. Your code does not appear to be appropriate for that product. I have removed the PowerShell tag from this question. You can find out the correct shell version by typing `echo $0` at the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net - there could be some word splitting issues. Try to use more verbose variable names then single letters. Note that your code prints `$i` not `$j`.

Using one variable using a value stored in another variable can be called ["indirection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection). [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) is not [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell). Unix shell was standardized by [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). One of Unix shells implementations is [Bash shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), and Bash has many extensions that are not in POSIX, like Bash arrays.

To indirectly access a variable, you can use *indirect expansion*:

```
for i in "${z[@]}"; do
   arrind="$i[@]"     # NOTE - [@] is here in variable value
   for j in "${!arrind}"; do
       printf "%s\n" "$j"
   done
done
```

or variable name reference:

```
for i in "${z[@]}"; do
   declare -n arrref="$i"
   for j in "${arrref[@]}"; do
        printf "%s\n" "$j"
   done
done
```

or `eval`, but `eval` is evil, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).